# Parsing a string using more than one delimiter XSLT 2 3

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have to insert a dot leader at the end of the first line of what could be several lines of text. If the string is over 37 characters, I display the first 37 characters, then the dot leader, and then the rest of the string flows to the following lines. I can get this to work using a space as a delimiter, but if there are no spaces the entire description gets pushed to the second line. So commas and hyphens need to be delimiters, as well, at the very least.

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="del" select="'[,|-|\s]+'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="string-tokens" select="tokenize($input, $del)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="substring">
        <xsl:value-of select="$string-tokens[not(. = $string-tokens[last()])]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$substring"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getFirstLine">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($remaining) &gt;= 37">
            <xsl:call-template name="getFirstLine">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remaining"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$remaining"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>
        
<xsl:template name="addDotLeader">      
    <xsl:variable name="descript" select="REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX,XXX-XXX,XXXX-XXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX" />
    <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($descript)" as="xs:integer"/>
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$length &gt;= 37">
            <xsl:variable name="remaining">
                <xsl:call-template name="getFirstLine">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$descript"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            
            <!-- print out first line -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$remaining"/>
            <!-- print out dot leader -->
            <xsl:text>&#x2002;</xsl:text><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><xsl:text>&#x2002;</xsl:text>
            <fo:block text-align-last="left" margin-left="8px">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($descript,$remaining)"/>
            </fo:block>
         </xsl:when>       
                      
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Description fits on first line -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$descript"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x2002;</xsl:text><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" /><xsl:text>&#x2002;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This almost works, except the dashes and commas are stripped out when it gets tokenized. When I try to print out the rest of the string, the substring-after fails because of the missing delimiters.

Actual output:

```
. . REMOVE THIS IS A TEST...........................
```

The actual string was `REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-LINE,XXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX,XXX-XXX,XXX-XXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX`

The desired output is:

```
. . REMOVE-THIS-IS-A-TEST-..........................
      LINE,XXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX,XXX-XXX,XXX-XXXXX,
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXX,XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, maybe start with capturing the first 37 characters before checking delimiters?

Comment: We can'just why `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($description,$remaining)"/>` fails if you don't show where you bind which value to the `description` variable. The `remaining` variable seems to be part of the strings with tokens removed so I suspect the `description` has those tokens and that way `remaining` without the tokens will never pass the `substring-after` test/check. But it is a guess, you don't show what is going on.

Comment: @Martin Honnen Yes, that's true, it fails because of the missing commas and hyphens. I was trying to simplify the code because I need help with preserving the delimiters. I'll add more details.